# How to update particular column value to today's date for the particular ID and keeping other value as previous date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE e_tab (
    e_id           NUMBER(10),
    eligible       VARCHAR2(30),
    assigned_date  TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO e_tab VALUES(1,'Y',null);
INSERT INTO e_tab VALUES(2,'Y',null);
INSERT INTO e_tab VALUES(3,null,null);
```

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    lv_flag NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(1)
    INTO lv_flag
    FROM
        e_tab
    WHERE
        assigned_date != sysdate;

    IF lv_flag < 1 THEN
        UPDATE e_tab
        SET
            assigned_date = current_timestamp
        WHERE
            eligible = 'Y';

    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

I have a table `e_tab` that I need to update based on the `eligible` column. If `eligible` column is `Y` then I need to update `assigned_date` column to `current date` and this will not happen frequently. Say for 2 E_ID that is 1 and 2 `eligible` column is `Y` so I have updated `assigned_date` column to today's date but for the third `e_id` i.e 3 that will be updated say after one day and will update `eligible` column to Y. Then, in this case, it should only update the third e_id to tomorrow's date and the previous one will be as it is.

Expected output:

```
+------+----------+-------------------------------+
| E_ID | ELIGIBLE |         ASSIGNED_DATE         |
+------+----------+-------------------------------+
|    1 | Y        | 02-02-22 3:53:46.449000000 PM |
|    2 | Y        | 02-02-22 3:53:46.449000000 PM |
|    3 | Y        | 03-02-22 3:53:46.449000000 AM |
+------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

Will my code work for this scenario? And also if few more `e_id` got added later then same will happen for all the `e_id`

Comment: You ask "will my code work for this scenario".  Well, does it work?  I'm assuming that since you're looking at the code and you're asking the question that the code isn't doing something that you want it to do but I'm not sure what it is failing to do correctly.  Calling a `timestamp` column `assigned_date` seems rather confusing.  And comparing a `timestamp` to `sysdate` is essentially always going to result in the two being not equal. My guess is that you think the second days' update is not working correctly, you want to eliminate the `count()` and just update where `assigned_date is null`

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for a quick turnaround but if I put ```assigned_date is null``` then it will update all the records to current date but. In my example for e_id 3 I will update ```eligible``` column to Y say tomorrow then ```assigned_date``` should be updated only for ```e_id``` 3  and previous ```e_id``` should not be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to need PL/SQL and can use a simple SQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE e_tab
SET eligible      = 'Y',
    assigned_date = CASE eligible
                    WHEN 'Y'
                    THEN current_date
                    ELSE current_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                    END
WHERE assigned_date IS NULL;
```

If you want to update all rows then remove the `WHERE` clause.

---

> Will my code work for this scenario?

No, because your `UPDATE` statement will never update the third row as it filters on `WHERE eligible = 'Y'` and for that row `eligible` is `NULL`.

---

#### Update

The requirements are not well communicated but you appear, now, to be asking to update the rows where `eligible` is `Y` and where there is not a value for `assigned_date`. For this you can use:

```sql
UPDATE e_tab
SET assigned_date = current_date
WHERE assigned_date IS NULL
AND   eligible = 'Y';
```

At a later date (i.e. tomorrow), you would then have to change the third row to have `eligible = 'Y'` and then, if you want it to be a separate process, could run that update statement again.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8075665cb8404bf8819834779d5584ea)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this code will always update the assigned_date column to current date and  if the column  ```eligible``` is null then it will add one day to it. But this wasn't my requirement. In my example for e_id 3 I will update eligible column to Y say tomorrow then assigned_date should be updated only for e_id 3 and previous e_id should not be changed

Comment: Thanks but this will update all the records to current_date. I need only those records to be updated when ```eligible``` flag is changing to Y. Lets assume I am updating ```eligible``` column of ```e_id``` 3 on 3rd Feb 2022. Then in this case for e_id 1 and 2 that will show as 2nd Feb only but on 3rd Feb I have changed the flag to Y for e_id 3. So, only e_id 3 should have 3rd Feb and e_id 1 & 2 will have 2nd Feb only

Comment: @Vicky "I need only those records to be updated when `eligible` flag is changing to Y." Then either set the date at the same time as you perform the update to change the `eligible` flag or use a trigger. The rest of your comment does not make sense as your sample data has `NULL` `assigned_date` values for rows 1 and 2 so when you run the `UPDATE` in my answer it will set the row 1 and 2 date but not 3. If tomorrow you update row 3 to `eligible = 'Y'` and then run the `UPDATE` again then it will set `assigned_date` to the current date when you run the query and will leave the other rows alone.

Comment: I've added a db<>fiddle to the answer which demonstrates the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration but I have one doubt if I will update the ```eligible``` column flag tomorrow i.e 3rd Feb then will this code work as I am expecting which is for 1 & 2 it should be 2nd Feb and for e_id 3 it should be tomorrow's date? Or I have to use trigger only?

Comment: @Vicky Look at the linked db<>fiddle. It does the update then waits for "tomorrow" (i.e. 5 seconds) then changes the third row and does the update again. What more do you want to see? If you are really concerned then try it yourself on your own database and wait the full day between updates.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all your help it should work for me. And one more thing could you please let me know how you have pasted the fiddle hyperlink? Because if I have to paste the link what I do is complete copy paste of the link but how to paste only hyperlink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241660/discussion-between-vicky-and-mt0).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger on e_tab so the `assignment_date` gets set whenever the eligible column value is set to 'Y'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER e_tab_biu
    before insert or update 
    on e_tab
    for each row
begin
    IF :NEW.eligible = 'Y' AND NVL(:OLD.eligible,'N') != :NEW.eligible THEN
      :NEW.assigned_date := current_timestamp;
    END IF;
end e_tab_biu;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for this but can't it be done without trigger ?

Answer (score 1):

```
`UPDATE e_tab
SET eligible      = 'Y',
assigned_date = CASE 
                WHEN eligible = 'Y'
                THEN sysdate
                ELSE sysdate + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                END
WHERE assigned_date IS NULL;`
```